# Weird stereo disparity map and point cloud in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, point-clouds, stereo-3d, disparity-mapping

I am trying to obtain the disparity map and the point cloud from two stereo images contained in the Middlebury dataset, but my results look incorrect.

These are the images from the [Middlebury dataset](https://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/#description) that I am using (imp version):
[image]

They come with the following calibration data:

```
cam0=[4841.191 0 1441.607; 0 4841.191 969.311; 0 0 1]
cam1=[4841.191 0 1598.24; 0 4841.191 969.311; 0 0 1]
doffs=156.633
baseline=170.458
width=2784
height=1992
ndisp=480
isint=0
vmin=28
vmax=452
dyavg=0.360
dymax=1.194
```

This is the code I wrote (based on MATLAB examples):

```
imageSize = [1992, 2784];
baseline = 170.458;

% calibration
k0 = [4841.191, 0, 1441.607;
    0, 4841.191, 969.311;
    0, 0, 1];
cameraParameters0 = cameraParameters("K", k0, "ImageSize", imageSize);

k1 = [4841.191, 0, 1598.24; 
    0, 4841.191, 969.311;
    0, 0, 1];
cameraParameters1 = cameraParameters("K", k1, "ImageSize", imageSize);

R10 = eye(3); % orientation of cam1 with respect to cam0
t10 = [baseline; 0; 0]; % translation of cam1 with respect to cam0
poseCamera1 = rigidtform3d(R10, t10); % pose of cam1 with respect to cam0

stereoParams = stereoParameters(cameraParameters0,cameraParameters1,poseCamera1); % calibrate stereo camera

I0 = imread("im0.png"); % load image 0
I1 = imread("im1.png"); % load image 1
[J0,J1,reprojectionMatrix] = rectifyStereoImages(I0,I1,stereoParams,OutputView='valid'); % rectify images

disparityRange = [0 128];
disparityMap = disparitySGM(im2gray(J0),im2gray(J1), 'DisparityRange', disparityRange);

figure
imshow(disparityMap,disparityRange)

figure
reconstructedPoints = reconstructScene(disparityMap,reprojectionMatrix);
pcshow(pointCloud(reconstructedPoints))
```

The disparity map that I get is shown below:
[image]

I tried to tinker with the "Uniqueness" and the "DisparityRange" parameters of the disparitySGM function, but I have not been able to get a disparity map which can actually be used.

I also tried to replace disparitySGM with disparityBM, and this is what I get:
[image]

As I expected given those disparity maps, the point cloud does not look good (this was generated from the disparity map obtained with disparitySGM):
[image]

I suspect there may be something wrong with the camera parameters I configured, but I am not sure about it. Any ideas regarding what I am doing wrong?